# jquery scheduler time-range picker

Tags: jquery, time

Is there any way that i can make scheduler according to this image?
I tried many layout but still didn't meet my criteria.

```
http://sundramfab.com/jquery/
```

We have try this layout and time-range also but still didn't work
This kind of time-range i want to do

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRlQU.png
```